# jQuery how to target children of siblings?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I'm having issues removing the active class in a certain div. I use two filters, but somehow if I click on one, the other filter also gets the active class removed. How can I only target and remove the active class of the children of siblings?

Here's my HTML:

```
<ul class="filter">
<li class="option"> <a class="link active">
<li class="option"> <a class="link">
<li class="option"> <a class="link">
</ul>

<ul class="filter2">
<li class="option"> <a class="link active">
<li class="option"> <a class="link">
<li class="option"> <a class="link">
</ul>
```

And here's my jQuery code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.link').bind('click', function() {
        // remove the active class from all elements with active class
        $('.active').removeClass('active')
        // add active class to clicked element
        $(this).addClass('active');
    });
});
```

Comment: You need to properly close the **li** and **a** tags first.

Comment: @Gerard FYI you don't need to close `li` (yes to `a`) :   [MDN li](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/li) *The end tag can be omitted if the list item is immediately followed by another <li> element, or if there is no more content in its parent element.*

Comment: Note that `.bind()` was deprecated ages ago in favor of `.on()`

Answer (score 2):

You can use `$(this).closest("ul")` to find th `ul` containing the element that was clicked, then `find` to find the `.active` elements in just that `ul`:

```
$('.link').on('click', function() {
    const $this = $(this);
    $this.closest("ul").find(".active").removeClass("active");
    $this.addClass('active');
});
```

---

Side note: I changed `bind` to `on`. `bind` has been deprecated for years.

Answer (score 0):

```
<div>
    <ul class="filter">
        <li class="option"> <a href="javascript:;" class="link active">1</a></li>
        <li class="option"> <a href="javascript:;" class="link">2</a></li>
        <li class="option"> <a href="javascript:;" class="link">3</a></li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="filter">
        <li class="option"> <a href="javascript:;" class="link active">4</a></li>
        <li class="option"> <a href="javascript:;" class="link">5</a></li>
        <li class="option"> <a href="javascript:;" class="link">6</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
<script>
    $(function() {
        $('.filter .link').click(function(){
            $(this).addClass('active').closest('.filter').find('.link').not(this).removeClass('active');
        });
    });
</script>
```

> check this one-liner